# Indicator for Top3 and ranking across ros

Tags: sas, row, transpose

What I am trying to do are following: I want to find out if a observation (A) is top 3 across others.

For example,

```
     A    B     C    D    E    F    G     H     TOP3-A

1   20    30   40   50   60   70    80   90       N

2   80    90   70   80    0    0     0    0       Y

3   70     0    0   80   90    0     0    0       Y

4   60    70   80   90    0    0     0    0       N
```

I am thinking transpose + rank + transpose + if <4 then Y else N, however it seems too cumbersome and to be honest as a newbie I do not how to code all these steps correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Your method would work, but there's a much simpler way of doing it.

You could use an array, which reads across rows, however I'm using an even easier way of reading across rows.

The `OF` statement can be used in conjunction with a summary function to calculate values across rather than down.  The `LARGEST` function returns the largest nth value from a range, so you can compare field A to the 3rd largest value in the row.

I've given you the answer to produce Y, N plus an alternative that produces 1, 0 which is even simpler.

```
data have;
input A    B     C    D    E    F    G     H;
datalines;
20    30   40   50   60   70    80   90
80    90   70   80    0    0     0    0
70     0    0   80   90    0     0    0
60    70   80   90    0    0     0    0
;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   if A >= largest(3, of A--H) then top3_A = 'Y'; /* A--H references all columns between A and H */
   else top3_A = 'N';
   /* or */
   top3_A2 = (A >= largest(3, of A--H)); /* returns 1 for true, 0 for flase */
run;
```